# Return the row with max value for each group

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following table with name **t2**:

```
  realm   |    race    | gender | total  
----------+------------+--------+--------
 Buffalo  | faerie     | F      |   5972
 Buffalo  | faerie     | M      |   2428
 Buffalo  | footballer | F      |   1954
 Buffalo  | footballer | M      |   2093
 Buffalo  | raccoon    | F      |   2118
 Buffalo  | raccoon    | M      |   1237
 Buffalo  | shark      | F      |  12497
 Buffalo  | shark      | M      |   3621
 Buffalo  | wizard     | F      |    468
 Buffalo  | wizard     | M      |  11079
 Camelot  | faerie     | F      |   2414
 Camelot  | faerie     | M      |   1455
```

I want to create a query that just selects the realm, race and gender with the highest total. Every time I use `GROUP BY` I keep getting both genders.

The output table looks like this:

```
  realm   |    race    | gender | total  
----------+------------+--------+--------
 Buffalo  | faerie     | F      |   5972
 Buffalo  | footballer | M      |   2093
 Buffalo  | raccoon    | F      |   2118
...
```

I think I have a very poor understanding on how to compare rows.
I can't figure out how to write the `WHERE` clause so that when I `GROUP BY realm,race,gender`, I only get 1 gender.

Comment: You don't show what SQL produced the output.  That would be helpful.

Comment: What should the output look like?  You say you want "the realm, race and gender with the highest total."  You say you "keep getting both genders".  Isn't the problem that you're getting 3 records when you expect 1?  `Buffalo | shark | F | 12497`

Comment: Let me edit the question with the query I wrote

Comment: Your query doesn't even use the `adventure` table.  How are all of the pieces of your "question" related?

Comment: I wrote "adventure" as a generic table. I assumed that my query wouldnt be needed to answer the question. the table is  "t2"

Comment: And the desired output should look like...?

Comment: The second table, there are more records those are the first 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A perfect use case for [**`DISTINCT ON`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (realm, race) *
FROM   tbl
ORDER  BY realm, race, total DESC;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=ff3995bb8a03c9bdea8e8e504cc8068d)*

Notably, the query has no `GROUP BY` at all.
Assuming total is `NOT NULL`, else append `NULLS LAST`.
In case of a tie, the winner is arbitrary unless you add more `ORDER BY` items to break the tie.

Detailed explanation:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Comment: Interesting strategy, it worked! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
select q.realm
, q.race
, q.gender
, q.total

from (
    Select t2.realm
    , t2.race
    , t2.gender
    , total
    , max(total) over (partition by t2.realm, t2.race) as maxtotal

    FROM adventure t2
) q
where q.total = q.maxtotal
```